# Stripline Background colour based on data

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a chart which measures volume (y-axis) against date (x-axis). I have an Event table, which stores meaningful events, which I'd like to display as a vertical stripline on the chart. When there's data there, the field `E_Text` will be populated.

I've tried various methods, and am currently trying to only display using a change to the background colour, as such ("`#00ffffff`" is no colour):

```
=iif(Fields!E_Text.Value="","#00ffffff","Orange")
```

However, this statement always returns true, despite the data always being there. Has anyone managed to get data-driven striplines working?

Comment: Presumably, at the moment the background colour is always clear - if you swap the two colours round, does it always come out as orange?

Comment: Yep, exactly that. It's as if it's not seeing the data - I have a tablix above it which shows the data is being read from the database correctly.

Comment: What's the link between your chart data, the x and y axis, and the `E_Text` field? As this is a chart the the stiplines will need some limits also like min and max limits. What happens if you force a single colour on the whole stripline without the expression?

Comment: A sample dataset or table would be handy?

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain you are capturing nulls?  A blank is something.  NULL and (blank) are two different things.  In SSRS Null is captured with Isnothing(), putting a value inside the parentheses.  I have never had tried data driven strip lines with this method but this in the past has been an issue.  Also can you test your function with an easier test first?  EG: Set a simple dataset up and set the background color up with a dataset we know to have a null and a positive value:

Create test dataset

```
declare @Person Table ( person varchar(8), orders int);

insert into @Person values ('Brett', 10),('Sean', null)

select * from @Person
```

Put a table from the toolbox in and populate it with the two columns.

Set the background property of the [orders] column cell to

```
=iif( isnothing(Fields!orders.value), "White", "Red")
```

I now see a white and a red, HOWEVER if I do this:

```
 =iif( Fields!orders.value = "", "White", "Red")
```

I get always white.

Comment: I've already handled nulls, by using an ISNULL(E_Text,'') when getting the data in. I suspect you can't do this with striplines - I've just started looking at conditional markers instead, and it seems to be working.